# Trying to connect socket.io to my custom domain server through host gator

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I am trying to have socket.io using my custom domain hosting server that I have through Host Gator.

I keep getting a CORS error when I try to do that.

Everything works fine if I host through the IP on my laptop. I can use other computers to connect with that IP as long as its on my network. I want to use my domains server so I can have other people connect as well. And by other people I mean a friend or two to show them.

I have tried putting
`Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
into my .htcaccess and that does not help anything

How I have the socket set up. If I use the IP of my laptop then it works but using my domain server IP gives me the CORS error.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join("mywebsiteip")));
```

Comment: don't you mean `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: yes. I made an edit